# File Locking in Python?

Tags: python, file, locking

I want to lock the file whenever I perform read/write operation on that file. No other program or function can access file until I do not release the file. How do you do this in Python?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock

or this:

http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf

To get file descriptor from a file-like object, you just need to call `fileno` method.

Comment: Be careful with this.  I would encourage use of a higher-level, well-debugged package because, absent deep thought, your use of these low-level functions is more likely to be imperfect.  For example of a subtle race condition, look at the comment by Thomas Guettler here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/65203-portalocker-cross-platform-posixnt-api-for-flock-s/

Comment: This is mind-bending, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907616/python-fcntl-does-not-lock-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

Google up zc.lockfile or portalocker.py. Both libraries can lock a file in a portable manner (windows and posix systems). I usually use zc.lockfile.

Comment: i used all library but any of them is not for my purpose. actually i want that whenever i read file no-one can read file and also write.