# Python fcntl does not lock as expected

Tags: python, fcntl

On a Debian-based OS (Ubuntu, Debian Squeeze), I'm using Python (2.7, 3.2) fcntl to lock a file. As I understand from what I read, fnctl.flock locks a file in a way, that an exception will be thrown if another client wants to lock the same file.

I built a little example, which I would expect to throw an excepiton, since I first lock the file, and then, immediately after, I try to lock it again:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import fcntl
fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'r'), fcntl.LOCK_EX)
try:
    fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'r'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    print("can't immediately write-lock the file ($!), blocking ...")
else:
    print("No error")
```

But the example just prints "No error".

If I split this code up to two clients running at the same time (one locking and then waiting, the other trying to lock after the first lock is already active), I get the same behavior - no effect at all.

Whats the explanation for this behavior?

**EDIT**:

Changes as requested by nightcracker, this version also prints "No error", although I would not expect that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import fcntl
import time
fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
try:
    fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
except IOError:
    print("can't immediately write-lock the file ($!), blocking ...")
else:
    print("No error")
```

Comment: There is a [catch regarding file locks within the same process](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html). So within a single process, threads will share the file lock.

Comment: Ding ding ding! Thank you, Bouke. That was my problem!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it. The error in my script is that I create a new file descriptor on each call:

```
fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'r'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
(...)
fcntl.flock(open('/tmp/locktest', 'r'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

Instead, I have to assign the file object to a variable and than try to lock:

```
f = open('/tmp/locktest', 'r')
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
(...)
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

Than I'm also getting the exception I wanted to see: `IOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable`. Now I have to think about in which cases it makes sense at all to use fcntl.

Comment: To be clear, the error isn't that you're creating a *new* file descriptor on each call, but that the *previous* file descriptor has been garbage collected (and the previous lock goes with it).  If you were to save both of those file descriptors to different variables, the script would work.

Comment: This answer is misleading.  The comment above by @Dustin is correct.

Answer (score 18):

Old post, but if anyone else finds it, I get this behaviour:

```python
>>> fcntl.flock(open('test.flock', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX)
>>> fcntl.flock(open('test.flock', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
# That didn't throw an exception

>>> f = open('test.flock', 'w')
>>> fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
>>> fcntl.flock(open('test.flock', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
>>> f.close()
>>> fcntl.flock(open('test.flock', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
# No exception
```

It looks like in the first case, the file is closed after the first line, presumably because the file object is inaccessible. Closing the file releases the lock.

Comment: Please note that since python 3.3 operations in fcntl module raise OSError instead of IOError

Answer (score 16):

I hade the same problem... I've solved it holding the opened file in a separate variable:

Won't work:

```
fcntl.lockf(open('/tmp/locktest', 'w'), fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

Works:

```
lockfile = open('/tmp/locktest', 'w')
fcntl.lockf(lockfile, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

I think that the first doesnt' works because the opened file is **garbage collected**, **closed** and the **lock released**.

Comment: Please note that you are using `lockf` whereas OP has used `flock` in the original post. These two are very different implementations!
Bad names, difficult to catch ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are two catches. According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.lockf):

1. > When operation is `LOCK_SH` or `LOCK_EX`, it can also be bitwise ORed with `LOCK_NB` to avoid blocking on lock acquisition. If `LOCK_NB` is used and the lock cannot be acquired, an `IOError` will be raised and the exception will have an `errno` attribute set to `EACCES` or `EAGAIN` (depending on the operating system; for portability, check for both values).

   You forgot to set `LOCK_NB`.
2. > On at least some systems, `LOCK_EX` can only be used if the file descriptor refers to a file opened for writing.

   You have a file opened for reading, which might not support `LOCK_EX` on your system.

Comment: thanks. But both changes (adding fcntl.LOCK_NB to the first lock AND open the file for writing) don't change the behavior, still getting "No error".

Comment: @ifischer: does `fcntl` work from C on your system? What version of Python do you use?

Comment: Tried both Python 2.7.1 and Python 3.2. Will try C later

Answer (score 3):

you could refer to this [post](https://gavv.github.io/blog/file-locks/) for more details of different lockin schemes.
As for your second question, use `fcntl` to get lock across different process(use `lockf` instead for simplicity). On linux `lockf` is just a wrapper for `fcntl`, both are associated with `(pid, inode)` pair.
1. use `fcntl.fcntl` to provide file lock across processes.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import fcntl
import struct


fd = open('/etc/mtab', 'r')
ppid = os.getpid()
print('parent pid: %d' % ppid)
lockdata = struct.pack('hhllh', fcntl.F_RDLCK, 0, 0, 0, ppid)
res = fcntl.fcntl(fd.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETLK, lockdata)
print('put read lock in parent process: %s' % str(struct.unpack('hhllh', res)))
if os.fork():
    os.wait()
    lockdata = struct.pack('hhllh', fcntl.F_UNLCK, 0, 0, 0, ppid)
    res = fcntl.fcntl(fd.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETLK, lockdata)
    print('release lock: %s' % str(struct.unpack('hhllh', res)))
else:
    cpid = os.getpid()
    print('child pid: %d' % cpid)
    lockdata = struct.pack('hhllh', fcntl.F_WRLCK, 0, 0, 0, cpid)
    try:
        fcntl.fcntl(fd.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETLK, lockdata)
    except OSError:
        res = fcntl.fcntl(fd.fileno(), fcntl.F_GETLK, lockdata)
        print('fail to get lock: %s' % str(struct.unpack('hhllh', res)))
    else:
        print('succeeded in getting lock')
```

2. use `fcntl.lockf`.

```
import os
import time
import fcntl

fd = open('/etc/mtab', 'w')
fcntl.lockf(fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
if os.fork():
    os.wait()
    fcntl.lockf(fd, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
else:
    try:
        fcntl.lockf(fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
    except IOError as e:
        print('failed to get lock')
    else:
        print('succeeded in getting lock')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the file descriptor (obtainable by calling the fileno() method of the file object). The code below throws an IOError when the same code is run in a separate interpreter.

```
>>> import fcntl
>>> thefile = open('/tmp/testfile')
>>> fd = thefile.fileno()
>>> fcntl.flock(fd, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/fcntl.html#fcntl.flock): _Perform the lock operation op on file descriptor fd (__file objects providing a fileno() method are accepted as well__)._

Comment: applying this does not change the behavior, still getting "No error", in opposite to what I would expect

Comment: @ifischer: Odd, I pasted the code above into two python interpreters on an Ubuntu machine and the first one completed, the second threw an exception.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
global f
f = open('/tmp/locktest', 'r')
```

When the file is closed the lock will vanish.

Comment: If it is two different process, then it is absolutely useless. Should use fcntl.flock